# How can i send my ETC from the ETH Wallet back to the ETC Wallet?

Tags: ether

i need your help.

I sent ETC from Coinbase to my ETH Wallet (Ledger Nano X).

The transaction: 0x1b007ab56371ecb70998d1a391d6ccf36cacf12c8a785140ffdb0d8a0c526148

How can i send my ETC from the ETH Wallet back to the ETC Wallet? I try with www.myetherwallet.com but i don`t found no way.

Or is it possible that an other person has a ETC Wallet with the same (as my) ETH Wallet id?

Thank you!

Comment: No such transaction hash `0x1b007ab56371ecb70998d1a391d6ccf36cacf12c8a785140ffdb0d8a0c526148`.

Comment: Well it was a ETC transaction so it's here: https://classic.etccoopexplorer.com/tx/0x1b007ab56371ecb70998d1a391d6ccf36cacf12c8a785140ffdb0d8a0c526148/internal_transactions

You should be able to login to an ETC wallet with the same private key and just transfer the ETC forward. One private key results in the same public key and public address in both networks

Comment: I don't get the private key from Coinbase or the ledger. Or does someone know a way?

Comment: I can help you recover your etc

Answer (score 1):

When you set up your Ledger Nano X it showed you a 24-word recovery phrase. This is a mnemnoic code.

You have to either use Ledger to create an Ethereum Account which uses that mnemonic code as a seed, if Ledger does support that, or find a BIP32, BIP39 and BIP44 compliant software wallet that allows you to enter your mnemonic code.

A mnemonic code serves as a seed to generate a vast amount of Ethereum accounts. So you will probably have to search some of those Ethereum accounts generated by your mnemonic seed (by supplying different derivation paths) before you find the correct one matching your Ethereum address.

Please research if the software wallet you want to use is open-source and well reviewed, since your coins are at stake. Only download the wallet from a trusted source, preferably the Github repository or the offical website of the organization that maintains it. To be 100% sure that the software wallet originated from the original source, perform a comparison of the checksums (optional).